# How to update SQL database with a PHP array?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

I wanted to update my SQL database with a PHP array, which is completed by users in another page. I made a nested `foreach` with one that runs through my table and the other through the database to modify each row with the new values in the table; instead it ran without errors, but put the last values in the table to each row in the database.

Here the code for the database update

```
<?php
@$rea = $_POST[rea];
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=si6;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$reponse = $bdd->prepare("update ca set rea = :rea");
print_r($rea);

foreach ($reponse as $v) {
    foreach ($rea as $value) {
        $reponse->bindValue(':rea', $rea[$value], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $reponse->execute();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your `UPDATE` statement needs a `WHERE` clause to specify which row(s) should be updated. If there's no `WHERE` clause, all rows are updated.

Comment: Also, `foreach ($reponse as $v) {` makes no sense at all.